# lightning:recordViewForm unable to display for guest community users

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-community, community-builder

asking does recordViewForm in communities only work display if the user is logged into Salesforce? I can't seem to get my output fields to display for a guest user. They're displayed and fine for a system administrator accessing the page in community.

I have a guest profile set up with read access on this object and the fields yet on the community he's unable to see the output fields.

Comment: Whats the OWD of that object for External Users?

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal, thanks and it helped me catch on that the object is controlled by another parent object which was private. However, I've tried changing that object for the default external access to public read only and still no luck for the guest user.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to Setup > Sharing Setting > Search for object > Click on "New" button > Create a Sharing Rule as Name not equal to '' > Share with Guest User of your community and Save.**